# Is there any adverb or phrase to introduce a supporting quotation?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm quoting from another writer to support my ideas. But I need an expression like "as according to" so as to introduce the quotation. I'd rather not use "as according to" since I've already used it twice.

Comment: How about: 
"as X put it...", "borrowing from X..." (slightly informal)
"paraphrasing X..." or "with reference to..."

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the "as": According to Goethe, "....."

You could also say:
To quote Goethe, To cite Goethe, As Goethe once wrote, Recalling Goethe's dictum/saying/, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The recognised way of doing this is to say *ibid.* when quoting the same source on subsequent occasions. It is Latin so needs to be quoted in italics and it is an abbreviation, so needs a full stop after it.

The full Latin word is *ibidem* and means 'in the same place'.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibid.)